# Looking for a flash MP3 player

Tags: javascript, flash, mp3

I need an mp3 player for a website which can be able to control play, pause, stop and seek using JavaScript, the player must not be a HTML 5.

Anyone knows if that kind of player exists, if it does what is the name of it. I searched everywhere and did not find a one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://flash-mp3-player.net/ First link on google, open source